# I have to filter the data using where in clause using predicates in C# (Get the data having the IDs passed in list)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, predicate

```
supplierIdsList.Add(246); 
supplierIdsList.Add(249); 
supplierIdsList.Add(1551260);

var flagPredicate = new List<Expression<Func<FlagEntity, bool>>>();

flagPredicate.Add(x => x.Deleted == "0" && x.Flag.IsDeleted == "0" && x.Flag.Status == "1" );
flagPredicate.Add(x => (x.EntityType == 5 && x.EntityId.Contains("1551260")) || (x.EntityType == 10 && x.EntityId.Contains(supplierIdsList)));

var flagData1 = GetAsync(flagPredicate).ToList();
```

Here is my code that is getting an error in `supplierIdsList` passes instead of getting data

I want to get data from database having `entity_id` IN `supplierIdsList`

Comment: Please provide more details. What is GetAsync() doing? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
flagPredicate.Add(x => (x.EntityType == 5 && x.EntityId.Contains("1551260")) || (x.EntityType == 10 && supplierIdsList.Contains(int.Parse(x.EntityId))));
```

It should work this way.